# VirtualBox verr_open_failed error

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to get VirtualBox working for Genymotion so that I can play "Clash of Clans" on it. But I am having some errors. I tried watching a few videos on the matter, but they just didn't fix my problem, so I came to Stack Exchange for some help, and I will appreciate any that is given!

So, I made a device called, "My Phone". 
But whenever I try to start it, I get this error message:

```
NtCreateFile(\Device\VBoxDrvStub) failed: 0xc000000e STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE (135 retries) (rc=-101)
```

And then it says "make sure the kernel module has been loaded successfully".

Followed by this:

```
Where: supR3HardenedWinReSpwan what: 3 VERR_OPEN_FAILED (-101) - File/Device open failed. Driver is probably stuck stopping/starting. Try 'sc.exe query vboxdrv' to get more information about its state. Rebooting may actually help.
```

Then I click okay and it says this:

```
The virtual machine 'My Phone' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). More details may be available in
```

--and then it directs me to the log.

[Here is the GitHub link to the log.](https://github.com/ColBaskerville/VirtualBox-error-log)

Any help is appreciated!